# UIPickerViewDelegate Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uipickerview

My code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var picherview: UIPickerView!

    var prodotti = ["AAAAA", "VVVV", "CCCC"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.picherview.dataSource = self
        self.picherview.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerview( _ : UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return prodotti.count
    }

    func pickerview( _ : UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return prodotti[row]
    }     //ci consente di determinare quale riga è stata selezionata

    func pickerview(_ : UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("Hai selezionato: \(prodotti[row])")}
    }
```

This code have error:

> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Any solution?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`. All of the methods have changed in Swift 3.

Answer (score 12):

Correct syntax of PickerView **Swift 3**

```
// DataSource
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

}

// Delegate

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

PickerView with done button  complete example in Swift 3

1. First Of all, Create a single view application in swift 3. Drag a text field & connect to view controller.
2. Implement in two  PickerView protocol named UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource
3. UIPickerViewDelegate & UIPickerViewDataSource  need to implement  methods like numberOfComponents,numberOfRowsInComponent,titleForRow
4. Picker View Look Like Below Image
   [image]
5. Full source are given bellow

   ```
    class ViewController:UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {
   //Text field Connect
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPickerTextField: UITextField!
   //Array declare
    let pickerArray = ["Bangladesh","India","Pakistan","USA"]
   var selectedRow = 0;
   //Picker View Object
   let picker = UIPickerView()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      //Don't forget to initialize pickerview delegate & datasource
      picker.delegate = self
       picker.dataSource = self
      txtPickerTextField.inputView = picker
      //Done Button function called
       doneButton();
    }
      public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView:  UIPickerView) -> Int  {
       return 1
     }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerArray.count
       }

       public func pickerView(_pickerView:UIPickerView,numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return pickerArray.count
        }

       func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
         return pickerArray[row]
       }
       func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
          selectedRow = row;
          txtPickerTextField.text = pickerArray[row]
          self.view.endEditing(false)
        }

        //begin  Doen Button function
       func doneButton(){

        let pickerView = picker
        pickerView.backgroundColor = .white
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true

        var toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
      toolBar.sizeToFit()

           let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "donePicker")
          let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
          let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "canclePicker")

          toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
          toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

          txtPickerTextField.inputView = pickerView
          txtPickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
         }


      func donePicker() {
       self.txtPickerTextField.text = pickerArray[selectedRow]
       txtPickerTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

         func canclePicker() {
            txtPickerTextField.resignFirstResponder()
           }
             //End  Doen Button function
            }
   ```
6. Complete Project Is given to Github. Github  Link: https://github.com/enamul95/PickerView1.git