# swift picker view with numbers displaying question marks

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I have added a picker view to my application and set it to an array of numbers. When I run the application all I see are question marks.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I have also tried using type Int and recieved the same results.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class myViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var settings: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterExit: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var daysTextField: UITextField!

    let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
    var hhh = Int()
    let seconds = 60.0

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int? {
        return numbers[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return numbers.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var days = numbers[row]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
```

[image]

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199826/uipickerviewdelegate-xcode-8-swift-3 , I think you need to learn about `uipickerviewdelegate` and `uipickerviewdatasource`

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code. Show your delegate and data source methods for the picker view.

Comment: there is my code @3stud1ant3

Comment: here is the code @ rmaddy

Comment: try removing `private` before `titleForRow` method

Comment: I still got question marks in the picker view @3stud1ant3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the following:

```
private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int? {
    return numbers[row]
}
```

This method should not be private and it should have the proper signature. This delegate method needs to return an optional `String`, not an optional `Int`.

```
private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return String(numbers[row])
}
```